# Loading search bar click when view loads

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi I am developing an app. I had a tab bar with three buttons. I had a search bar in third view.My requirement is when i click the third tab i need search bar click with keyboard appears as shown in below image. Is it possible? [image]

Comment: Try the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11151139/656600 and accept it if it helps.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the search bar to "befomeFirstResponder". It will act as if the user had tapped on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: This is the code. I was posting from my iPhone so I couldn't easily put it.

Answer (score 3):

In your third  tap action event, set your instance of the UISearchBar's setHidden to NO and make it the becomeFirstResponder.  For ex:

```
[self.search setHidden:NO]; 
[self.search becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 2):

When Segment value changed. try this

```
-(void) segmentValueChanged 
{
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

becomeFirstResponder method will focus that control when you call it.